# iOS get Device Token after device has been registered for push notifications?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

I know that you can get the Device Token with the method:-

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
```

However if I understand correctly this method only gets called the first time the app runs and the user accepts the notification request. On subsequent restarts of the app the method never gets called again.

So my question is this - is there any other way to access the Device Token after the user has accepted notifications?

Edit - I know all of that the device is online and the provisional profile is linked to the app id because I can receive Push notifications. Receiving push notifications is not the problem - getting the Device Token and storing it in Parse is what I want to achieve.

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps `- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error` gets called. If it is so, you can have a look at the error and that will give you an idea of what's going wrong.

Comment: Thanks xardas that really helped the error handler does get called- it seems it was a provisioning profile problem afterall - see Smikey's answer below. But its strange that it was still receiving pushes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, try checking your provisioning profile again. It sounds like you may be using one with a wildcard. You might be receiving pushes from the server because you originally deployed with a correct profile, however if you've changed to using a wildcard profile (a team profile for example), you won't be registering for remote notifications correctly...

Answer (score 11):

You're wrong.

From the `-application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:` documentation:

> The delegate receives this message after the `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:` method of `UIApplication` is invoked and there is no error in the registration process [...] This method could be called in other rare circumstances, such as when the user launches an app after having restored a device from data that is not the device’s backup data. In this exceptional case, the app won’t know the new device’s token until the user launches it.

From the Apple Push notification guide:

> Moreover, never cache a device token and give that to your provider; always get the token from the system whenever you need it. If your application has previously registered, calling `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:` results in the operating system passing the device token to the delegate immediately without incurring additional overhead. Also note that the delegate method may be called any time the device token changes, not just in response to your app registering or re-registering.

In other words that method is called whenever you call `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:` and the operation is successful, as well as at other times when the token changes

EDIT:

> If a cellular or Wi-Fi connection is not available, neither the `application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:` method or the `application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:` method is called. For Wi-Fi connections, this sometimes occurs when the device cannot connect with APNs over port 5223.

Alternatively make sure you are building with a provisioning profile linked to an app id that has Push notification entitlements

Comment: Ok so perhaps i still don't understand i am calling     'registerForRemoteNotificationTypes' and i have put log statements and a break point in 'didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken' - however I'm not hitting the break point or getting those Log messages - is there something else I am doing wrong?

Comment: I know all of that the device is online and the provisional profile is linked to the app id because I can receive Push notifications. Let me be clear receiving push notifications is not the problem - getting the Device Token and storing it in Parse is what I want to achieve.

Comment: This works for me. Notification debugging is tricky and much doesn't work correctly in the simulator. Make sure you're running on a device.

Comment: Works for me as well. This should be marked as the right answer. Crazy how hard this was to find 

Answer (score 0):

Use below method in didiFinishLaunchingWithOption

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
```

May this will work for your problem

Comment: The problem is that once registerForRemoteNotificationTypes has executed once, it won't call didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken again. Even if you delete the app, call unRegister etc, the app will not call didRegisterForRemote... ever again.